# Strange binding adapter click listener behaviour kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-binding-adapter

```
<ConstraintLayout
    app:clickListener="@{1}"> // wont work

    <LinearLayout>            // works here

       <TextView/>
       <ImageView/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

I have encountered a strange behaviour that I never met before. I am trying to make the constraint layout clickable so I have a binding adapter to init the click listener.

```
@BindingAdapter("clickListener")
fun clickListener(view: ViewGroup, data: Int){
    view.setOnClickListener{
        println("Click")
    }
}
```

The constraint layout is not listening to my clicks. By chance, I created the linear layout, moved the `app:clickListener="@{1}"` from the constraint layout to linear layout. This will work and clicks are listened. If I remove the linear layout and add `app:clickListener="@{1}"` to either the Textview or ImageView or both, clicks are listened too. It just won't work no matter what at the root level.

Is there an explanation for this? I am trying to get rid of the linear layout as it adds a layer to the view but this is the only way that I can have to make it work and **please note that** I will only use binding adapter for this case.

Comment: you added viewgroups as first parameter so you need to pass view from  xml         
app:clickListener="@{(v) ->{v,1}"

Comment: Thanks but that is not working.